# Difficulty using trignometric functions in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

in an iphone application i want to use the trignometic functions. but the answer is not coming correctly.
this is my code:

```
#include"math.h"
double tri;
tri=sin(90);
printf("%lf",tri);
```

for this the answer is coming as 0.893977
how can i correct the code to get the answer as 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double tri; 
tri=sin(90.0 * 3.1415926/180.0); 
printf("%lf",tri);
```

Comment: You can also use `M_PI` (#defined in math.h) for the pi value if you prefer to use predefined constants.

Answer (score 4):

The arguments to standard trigonometric functions should be supplied in radians, not degrees.